# Accuracy Python vs. Matlab and strange behaviour

Tags: python, matlab, floating-accuracy

I discover a very strange behaviour between Matlab and Python. First, I try to explain:

I am translating a Matlab Code to Python and it seems to work very well. I need to determine the eigenvalues of matrix A for a calculation and after some algebra I discover that a quantity is not the same as in matlab. So I copy the matrix A from Python to Matlab with 4 digits and I got the same "wrong" result as in Python. So I copy now the same Matrix A from Python but this time with 15 digits and the result in Matlab is right. Second, I copy the Matrix A from Python to Matlab with 20 digits and the result is the "wrong" one. I can't understand why Matlab shows the right result only for 15 digits. The funny thing is, that matlab lead to the same result if I take 4 digits or 20 digits. Only for 15 digits after the decimal seperator matlab calculate the desired result.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Matlab determines the result right (since I know the answer) but Python is wrong.

If someone need more explanation I try to extend my question, but the whole calculation is very complicated, so I cannot upload the whole code.

Today, I try to find the problem and I discover, that the result from `eigh`.
I need to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric Toeplitz matrix A with

```
    w, v = np.linalg.eigh(A, UPLO='U')
```

I have an eigenvalue that is zero and the result differs for this eigenvalue: `7.13188e-14` vs.`3.33955e-14`. Although the matrix A is in both cases the same, the result varies. How can that be the case?

Comment: You could include in question the various inputs and outputs you tried. If its a large matrix, you could test with some simple cases (small matrices), and show those. The symptoms suggest that you have values that are near some situation, such that slight numeric errors (roundoffs) cause different results. For example, values might "cancel" out in one calculation, but not in another. You need to show what is "right" and what is "wrong", for anyone to say more. If the highest precision one is "wrong", then you likely need to rework your approach, to avoid whatever condition is causing trouble.

Comment: Please read [mre]. We cannot help you without knowing exactly what you are doing. Show us the code with the data copied in. But your issue is likely that your matrix is poorly conditioned, which means that very small changes will have outsize influence on the results of eigenvalue analysis.

Comment: I extend my question and I found that the determination of eigenvalues varies, although the code and the matrix is the same (I already check that the matrix is exactly the same).  Unfortunately, this influences my postprocessing and lead to different results.